# Will NPC Heroes use throwing weapons in melee if its the last one?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

In Warband, if I give a hero all throwing axes, and he's down to the last throwing axe, will he start using it in melee or just chuck the axe and end up punching people?

Answer (score 2):

He will chuck the axe and end up punching people. No, there is no way to make a companion use all but one of their throwing weapons. Don't be so cheap, and buy them a one hander, they will automatically switch to it after running out of throwing weapons ;)

Comment: Hi eMi, did you try this out in game?  Any way you can get a screen shot or something?

Comment: At least I can't, cause I don't own the game anymore. But I know it, as I tried it in the past. Maybe someone else can try it and prove it. If not u can trust in or not ;)